# Playframework - build play application on build server

Tags: playframework

At the moment I am searching for a possibility to build web applications written with the Play framework with maven.

In the end I would like to have the following process on the build server:

- check out the application from the version control system
- do a "play war"
- do a assembly to tar.gz

But I don't want to install the play framework and all of its versions to the build server. I don't want to switch between play versions on the build server just because application one is build with play version x and application two is expecting play version y. Is there a way to include the play version inside the dependencies and so somehow decouple the framework+application from the build tool? (with maven or some other build tool) I'm not relying on maven so I'm looking forward for every idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently no, you will need the framework as it contains all the python scripts used to build the project.

In PlayFramework 2.0 the build will be managed via sbt, which may facilitate the process.

Comment: Thank you very much. So I do have to wait for PlayFramework 2.0 to get it in production.

Comment: well, Play 1.x is "production ready", but it will be more complex to automate, that's all :)

Comment: I think this maven plugin helps me a lot in getting closer to my goal using play in our environment: http://code.google.com/p/maven-play-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it but I've followed the instruction in here http://community.jboss.org/blogs/thomas.heute/2011/06/29/play-framework-on-jboss-as-7 and it works with Jboss. I think Maven might be similar